# Counting Regular polygons in Complete Graphs

Tags: combinatorics, polygons

The figure shows the correct $24-$gon, which held all the diagonals.

a) Find out how we got right triangles and squares (question for arbitrary $n$)?

b) How this problem can be generalized (if it is possible, of course)?

[image]

[image]

**My work so far:**

That there were squares, you need to have the diagonals are perpendicular. This means that the number of vertices of a multiple of $4$. Similarly, to get the equilateral triangles, the number of vertices must be a multiple of $3$. If $n = 5$, for example, or squares or triangles will not. It does not bother. How to calculate the number of regular polygons? The main difficulty here is to count the number of degenerate triangles, ie triples diagonal angles of 60, which intersect at the same point, if it is not the center.

***Addition:***

**Problem: Find the number of regular polygons in the complete graph**

For example:

Let $D_3(n) -$ number of equilateral triangles in a complete graph with $n$ vertices, $D_4(n) -$number of squares in a complete graph with $n$ vertices.

Then $3 \not| n \Rightarrow D_(n)=0$, for  example, $D_3(5)=0$,

$4 \not| n \Rightarrow D_(n)=0$, for  example, $D_4(5)=0$.

But $3|24$ and $4|n$, then $D_3(24)>0$ and $D_4(24)>0$.

*Question:* $D_3(24)-?, D_4(24)-?, D_3(n)-?, D_4(n)-?, D_k(n)-?$

Comment: Figure 2 shows equilateral triangles. Is that what you meant by "right" triangles?

Comment: Is this machine translated? I can't parse a single sentence in this question...

Comment: I do not know much English. I use machine translation